# How to intuitively see a homeomorphism of the following "triangle" space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Construction of the space:**  Take two line segments AB and BC and think of them as half open-half closed intervals which are open on the A and C points.  Now connect them at B so that you have formed something that looks like a partial triangle ABC (missing AC).  Now draw a dotted line from A to C, allowing for curvature.

What I am attempting to describe should look like a triangle except where the 3rd side is "open", in the topological sense.

**Question:** If I take two points, x and y, one on each of the straight sides of the triangle and in roughly the middle part (not endpoints), does there exist a homeomorphism $h$ of the triangle to itself such that $h(x)=y$.  I have a feeling we can do this but I am having trouble seeing how to "stretch" the space into the other, in the sense that some homeomorphisms are described in topology (e.g. donut vs coffee cup).

Comment: Yes. Distort it continuously so that $|AB|=|BC|$, and the open edge is straight; you now have an isosceles triangle open on one edge. You can also carry out the distortion so that $x$ and $y$ are at the midpoints of their sides. Now just turn the triangle over, i.e., rotate it $180°$ about the bisector of $\angle B$.

Comment: Thank you Brian M. Scott, I wasn't sure of whether I could "flip the triangle over".  So in looking for homeomorphic objects what is the short-list of operations that I can perform?

Comment: I’m not sure that I can answer that question usefully, since I normally think about homeomorphisms in pretty abstract terms. If you’re thinking of objects in $\Bbb R^3$, though, the usual intuitive notions of stretching and shrinking and all rigid motions (rotations, translations) certainly qualify.

Answer (score 1):

The question was settled in the comments of Brian M. Scott.